# RMSE between two tables in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two tables x and y in Matlab that contain one column each of equal length. I just want to compute the RMSE between the two columns, but somehow I cannot do this simple operation.

`rmse = sqrt(sum((x(:)-(y)(:)).^2)/1000)`

It gives me an invalid array indexing error. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MATLAB you can only index variables, but not expressions. But that's exactly what you try to do with

```
(y)(:)
```

as `(y)` is an expression. Instead use

```
y(:)
```